# is this a valid assignment for array

Tags: c, arrays

Here is a draft of a code. I wanted to know if it is correct to use array[j++]. Also if correct, will j increment first and then assign value or other way round

```
int i=0, j=0;
int array[10];
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
array[j++] = i; /*Is this valid? the j++ part inside an array*/
}
```

Comment: Try it and you'll know.

Comment: Now.. after you tried it, what did you get? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct, but a bit confusing to read. It's better like this:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i != 10; ++i, ++j)
{
    array[j] = i;
}
```

Or simply:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
{
    array[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: Why is that `;` after the loop?

Comment: Yeah. Its just that i wrote some code here to understand the increment part.. Thank you though..

Comment: @KerrekSB hahaha.. nice one :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun; This is the real use of 5 minutes of buffer after giving an answer :)

Comment: @haccks Indeed.. I was looking at the time and was hoping that he'll do it after so people won't think I'm crazy ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun; Now better to remove your comment otherwise people will think ... you are **Iron Man** (if you remember that girl :D).

Comment: @haccks LOL, you still remember that.. :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun; Hahaha...Whenever I see any of your comment or answer, my mind switch back to that conversation :D ( I will never forget that moment).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is valid, but it will increment `j` after the assignment. To increment `j` before the assignment, you need to do `++j`

This is the concept of [pre-increment vs. post-increment.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators)

Answer (score 0):

```
array[j++] = i;
```

is equivalent to:

```
array[j] = i;
j++;
```

It's valid, and `j` increments after the assignment.

The one that would invoke undefined behavior is this:

```
array[i++] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its valid. `array[j++]` increments `j` not the element at at index `j`.

```
array[j++] = *( array + (j++) ) ==> It just increments j, does not modify array
```